# scala foreach with Unit passed in

Tags: scala, foreach

I'm a very beginner to Scala and please excuse my ignorance.

Here is a snippet whose behavior is a bit strange to understand.

`def times(n: Int) = (body: Unit) => (0 until n) foreach(n=>body)`

`times(5){
        println("index")
    }`

The output is: index printed only once.

However, this one:

`def times(n: Int) = (0 until n) foreach(n=>println("index"))`

prints it 10 times.

Answer (score 3):

```
def times(n: Int) = (body: Unit) => (0 until n) foreach(n=>body)
```

Method `times` creates function that takes `Unit` and returns `Unit`.

`times(5)` takes `Unit`, so `times(5){ println("index") }` evaluates its parameter `println("index")` to `Unit`.

To evaluate `println("index")` `n` times you have to pass it as function like this:

```
def times(n: Int) = (body: Unit => Unit) => (0 until n) foreach(_ => body())
```

Usage:

```
times(5){ _ => println("index") }
```

It could be better to use `parameter groups` and `pass by name`:

```
def times(n: Int)(body: => Unit) { (0 until n) foreach( _ => body) }
```

Usage:

```
scala> times(5){ println("index") }
index
index
index
index
index
```

Answer (score 2):

Your second function should work as expected.

Your first function, however, is mistyped, you need it to be this to be correct:

```
def times(n: Int)(body: => Unit) = (0 until n) foreach(n=>body)
```

Otherwise the semantic is the following. (Your function:)

```
def times(n: Int) = (body: Unit) => (0 until n) foreach(n=>body)
```

If you call `times(n)` it will return a `function` that takes `Unit` as parameter and runs `(0 until n) foreach(n => body)`

Comment: Shouldn't you actually pass the function by name in the curried version? like `def times(n : Int)(body: => Unit) = (0 until n) foreach(n => body)`

Comment: Yay, after some tinkering with Scala I *think* I'm starting to understand a few things... ;)

Answer (score 1):

There's a tendency at first to think of `Unit` as meaning "a block of code", which is simply not true. `Unit` has one value: `()`. That's it.

So the value of `body` when you do `times(5){ println("index") }` will *not* be `{ println("index") }`, it will be `()`. If you do `()` five times, nothing will happen five times.

What happens is that `{ println("index") }` is executed, something is printed, and then `Unit` is returned and assigned to `body`. Like this:

```
scala> val body = { println("index") }
index
body: Unit = ()

scala> (0 until 5) foreach {n => body}

scala>
```

You can do what you want using a by-name parameter, in which case the parameter will represent *an expression that evaluates to `Unit`*, instead of just being `Unit`. For example:

```
def times(n: Int)(body: => Unit) = (0 until n) foreach(n=>body)
```

The `=>` prefixing the parameter type means the parameter is passed by name. It *does not change* the type, it changes the [evalutation strategy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Evaluation_strategy) (see the link for more information).

Comment: Functions can receive by-name parameters; you're forced to use the sugared syntax, but that's it.  E.g. `(Monoid[Int].mappend _): (Int, => Int) => Int`.